# What's producing this KeyError while parsing this xml file?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, minidom

I have an xml file that I'm trying to parse. Here's a sample

```
</Event>


-<Event timestamp="2016-08-14T14:23:33.634" id="1713385925" 
version="1471181110290" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:25:11" y="11.0" 
x="89.7" outcome="0" team_id="148" player_id="51327" sec="8" min="23" 
period_id="1" type_id="4" event_id="205">

<Q id="733814222" qualifier_id="265"/>

<Q id="481660420" qualifier_id="286"/>

<Q id="813378778" qualifier_id="152"/>

<Q id="570443899" qualifier_id="56" value="Right"/>

<Q id="420312891" qualifier_id="233" value="248"/>

<Q id="1186861264" qualifier_id="13"/>

</Event>


-<Event timestamp="2016-08-14T14:23:33.634" id="1635888622" 
version="1471181110289" last_modified="2016-08-14T14:25:11" y="89.0" 
x="10.3" outcome="1" team_id="143" player_id="169007" sec="8" min="23" 
period_id="1" type_id="4" event_id="248">

<Q id="1871787686" qualifier_id="56" value="Back"/>

<Q id="176295814" qualifier_id="13"/>

<Q id="69346842" qualifier_id="233" value="205"/>

<Q id="1588029344" qualifier_id="265"/>

<Q id="559785299" qualifier_id="285"/>

<Q id="380723313" qualifier_id="152"/>
```

It's full of events like these. I can access all the other attributes(`outcome`,`type_id` etc) and child tags but can't do that for the attribute values of `player_id`.
The error is - 
[image]
And here's a sample of the xmldom code I'm using to parse it.

```
xml = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("Games")[0]
Events = xml.getElementsByTagName("Event")

for event in Events:
    typeid = event.attributes["type_id"]
    typeidval = typeid.value

    player = event.attributes["player_id"]
    playeridval = player.value

    teamid = event.attributes["team_id"]
    teamidval = teamid.value

    outcomeid = event.attributes["outcome"]
    outcomeidval = outcomeid.value
```

Could someone help me out with the xmldom/minidom code to get through this problem? What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not all your Event tags have a `player_id` attribute, apparently.

Comment: Ah that indeed might be the case. How do I work around this? @MartijnPieters

Comment: Use `ElementTree` instead of `minidom`, which have a more modern interface.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly fix would be to handle the exception for the `player_id` attribute and set the value to `""` when an exception is thrown:

```
try:
    player = event.attributes["player_id"]
    playeridval = player.value
except:
    playeridval = ""
```

Comment: Why would that be ugly? It looks like it would work out in theory @glhr

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner approach:

```
player = event.attributes.get("player_id",None)
playeridval = player.value if player else ""
```